# Vue js modal: mixin or plugin?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, structure, vue.js, mixins

I have two different types of modals: large modals (800x500) and small modals (300x200).

From within different components across my website I want to open these modals, all with different content inside. And even **some of the modals should open other modals as well**. I'm currently thinking about this app structure:

```
modals/
|- largeModals/
|   |- profile.vue
|   |- messages.vue
|- smallModals/
|   |- enter.vue
|   |- disable.vue
|   |- confirm.vue
|- largeModal.vue
|- smallModal.vue
```

*`largeModal.vue` and `smallModal.vue` are the basic layout components, the files in the folders are the contents of the modals.*

What would be the best way to open a new modal from within other components? It's very important that a parameter can be passed. So for example the `profile` modal should receive a `user_id` to query the database before the user profile is shown.

[This project](https://github.com/ElemeFE/vue-popup) for example is using the `Mixin` method to display modals, but some others suggest to use a `Plugin` so there are less problems with overwrites.

What would be the best way to open a modal from within any component, or from within another modal, like `$this.openModal('profile', userId)`? And why? I'm using Vue.js 2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to create global event bus

```
//Example
Vue.EVENTS = new Vue()
```

As far as it is global, all events that are emitted through `EVENTS` could be listened anywhere in your component tree.

For example, check how this plugin works: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/